# Converting a normal regular RegEx to one in SAS

Tags: regex, sas

Although reading SAS documentation and various example pages, I am struggeling to convert a slightly more complicated RegEx to SAS syntax. I using the command `prxchange`. This is what I came up so far convert a filename-string like `pre_31DEC2019_299792458.xls` to an integer number (of length 8) `299792458` inside a SAS data step:

```
tmp=prxchange('s/pre_([a-zA-Z0-9]{8,9})_([0-9]{1,16})\.xls/\2/g',-1,have);
want=input(tmp,8.);
```

The error message I have points to somewhere else in the code, but I am rather certain that it is those two lines which cause a problem since leaving out the two quoted lines makes the SAS error message vanish.

#### References

- [Inofficial SAS howto on RegEx](https://www.lexjansen.com/wuss/2014/79_Final_Paper_PDF.pdf) suggests that I could use standard RegExes.

Comment: Can, can you share the error message? Is it a top military secret or something?

Comment: I don't know anything about SAS or this function but your string holds upper-case letters and your pattern searches for lower-case, resulting in *no* match. Maybe that causes an error?

Comment: @JvdV: I edited the regex accordingly. Internally, I did a conversion to lower case before.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: Not quite, but the system does run in a sandbox, so I cannot simply copy'n'paste the lengthy SAS error log.

Comment: How well formed are your input strings?  Do you just need the last 8 characters before the period that marks the file extension?  Or do some of the values have a different number of digits there? Or non-digits there?

Comment: Well your regex is trying to capture the whole string but you are interested in capture group #2 but I don't see any code which specifically accesses that capture group so you are essentially verifying that the string is in the expected format and trying to create an integer out of the entire string? `\d+(?=\.xls)` would extract just the integer piece `299792458`

Comment: SAS space fills variables out to variable length, so need to either `trim(have)` or add `\s*$` to the end of your regex pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why use regex at all?

```
want = input(scan(have,-2,'._'),32.);
```

Comment: Very good point (as usual), but I would really be keen to understand how to use the `[a-z]{1,4}` syntax in SAS, in general.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
tmp = prxchange('s/^pre_[A-Za-z0-9]+_([0-9]+)\.xls$/$1/', -1, have);
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PFd1GK/1)

**Details**

- `s/` - substitution action (we are replacing the match)
- `^`  -  start of string
- `pre_` - a literal prefix
- `[A-Za-z0-9]+`  - one or more alphanumeric ASCII chars (note you may simply use `.*` here instead if there can be anything)
- `_`  - an underscore
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `\.xls$` - `.xls` at the end of string
- `$1` - the whole match, the whole string matched, will be replaced with the contents of Group 1.

As far as the [`prxchange` function](https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=vdmmlcdc&cdcVersion=8.1&docsetId=ds2ref&docsetTarget=p1jpfpfp9qw3ron1501s0x5lpjw9.htm&locale=en) is concerned, note that it replaces all occurrences of the pattern once you pass `-1` as the *times* argument, thus, no `g` flag is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your lines. My biggest issue is not so much the RegEx, but how to do a `[abc]{1,2}` in SAS' `prxchange`. Is it really one-to-one to usual RegExes? Meaning that the expression here would search for any combination `a, b, c, aa, ab, ac, ba, bb, bc, ca, cb, cc` in SAS as well?

Comment: @B--rian Yes, `[abc]{1,2}` matches one or two occurrences of either `a`, `b` or `c`.

Answer (score 0):

Many ways you could try:

```
data _null_;
a="pre_31DEC2019_299792458.xls";
b=input(prxchange('s/.*\_(.*)\..*/$1/',-1,a),12.);
c=input(prxchange('s/.*(\d{9}).*/$1/',-1,a),12.);
d=input(prxchange('s/.*(?<=\_)(\d+).*/$1/',-1,a),12.);
put _all_;
run;
```

.* means any one character many times; for b, the numbers you need are between _and .; for c, it is 9 digitals; for d, it look behind "_" to find digitals.